# google-cloud-sql cannot get connected with the database

Tags: google-cloud-sql

Im new to cloud sql can you please help me to resolve the same
I created instance using cloud sql under my existing project

This is the sample one i have created.

My servlet code contains the following connection details:

```
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");
     url = "jdbc:google:mysql://shobhas-helloworld:shobhas-db/shoba?user=root";

     Connection conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url);
```

Error:

```
  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:216)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at com.example.shobhashelloworld.LoginServlet.doGet(LoginServlet.java:43)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
        at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:97)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like your application is running on a dev app server.
Could you take a look at [App Engine documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/#connect_and_post)? The code snippet there contains examples on how to connect to a local database or a remote Cloud SQL instance during development.

Comment: I cant get your point, what is meant by dev app server? I need to create a database and tables for my application, Can you please elaborate the answer.

Comment: Dev app server is the [development sever](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver) that you install and run on your local machine:

Comment: And if you want to create a database and tables, you can use the [MySQL client](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/mysql-client) or other [admin tools](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/admin-tools) to do that.

Answer (score 0):

When running an application on AppEngine please ensure that the [driver is enabled](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/#enable_connector_j)